# A mesh of Cookie in Header & HttpOnly token - secure "enough"?

Tags: xss, csrf, api, http-proxy

This is another attempt of mine to make sense of securing my web-app, which is built with two frameworks:

1. Django REST API - serves as the backend. It generates both a token upon correct login, and a CSRF-Token.
2. Nuxt.js - This is a framework built on top of Vue.js, **and enables server-side-rendering**. The latter feature is worth mentioning here because I have to use cookies to retrieve the user auth details when a server-side request is made.

Since storing a single auth token in Local Storage is susceptible to XSS, and cookies open the possibility of a CSRF attack, Here's what I've come up with:

1. The frontend is running in [proxy mode](https://github.com/nuxt-community/proxy-module), using the http-proxy middleware. This solves the issue with CORS.
2. Upon successful login, the Django backend sets two cookies:

   1. A completely unsecured CSRF cookie, visible to all, and that is of course automatically sent with every request.
   2. Another `HttpOnly` only cookie called `auth_cookie`, which contains a different, secret token.
3. The frontend, on its part, attaches to **every request** the CSRF token by reading the cookie value.
4. Server-side, we determine if a user is authorized by doing these checks:

   1. Is a `CSRF-Token` value present?
   2. Is a `CSRF-Token` cookie present?
   3. Do the values of the `CSRF-Token` *token* and the `CSRF-Token` *cookie* match?
   4. Is the `HttpOnly` cookie `auth_cookie` present, and does it match the token associated with the user in the database?

From my little understanding, this protects from XSS (on the token front at least) because JavaScript attacks won't be able to read the value of the `auth_cookie`, and from CSRF because these attacks can't send custom headers.

The only thing I'm banging my head with is the proxy part. On the Wikipedia page for [Cross-site request forgrey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Cookie-to-header_token) it says this about the cookie to header pattern:

> The protection provided by this technique can be thwarted if the
>   target website disables its same-origin policy using one of the
>   following techniques:
>
> - Permissive Access-Control-Allow-Origin Cross-origin resource sharing header (with asterisk argument)

I didn't do that, but isn't what I did by running my frontend framework, Nuxt.js, in proxy mode equivalent? Have I completely re-exposed my app?

Comment: Can you explain how running a proxy is equivalent to allowing CORS? You need to allow CORS, if the web application loads from a different domain while API server sits on a different domain, i.e. have different origins. If the app loads in the browser via the proxy, while the requests go thru the proxy to the AP server, then you don't need to have any CORS headers (i.e. no CORS requests allowed). If that is not the case, then I suggest to put appropriate origins in the CORS headers for the API server.

Comment: @bhorkarg - can you please explain to me how it isn't? (I'm genuinely not sure). If I turn off the proxy, I'm getting `OPTIONS` and some endpoints are failing (because as said in OP, I'm attaching a non-standard header client-side); if I turn it back on, I can do all actions, regardless of CORS settings. So obviously the presence of such proxy is affecting at least my need for CORS.

Comment: Allowing CORS will allow the browser to execute a request from a different origin from the original. A proxy is simply an intermediary server. Different concepts :). It seems your API server is on a different domain than web app, that's why you get the OPTIONS (preflight request). And your proxy is likely in the same origin as your web app, that's why there is no CORS involved since all the requests likely to thru the proxy instead of directly talking to the API server.

Comment: So, the proxy *isn’t* allowing the browser to execute from a different origin? I mean, when I turn it off I go back to preflight. When on, no need for that.

Comment: I think I am confusing you :).  Let's say your proxy is located at example.com and your web app loads from example.com, while your API server is apiserver.com. In this case, you see, your proxy and your web app have the same origin, so the browser is not concerned with CORS.

On the other hand, if you don't have a proxy, then web app loads from example.com while API server is at apiserver.com. You see, different origins. So the browser will not allow CORS unless you allow it at the API server (using CORS headers). Hence the browser sends the preflight options request.

Comment: Is this the case? if I assumed this correctly.

Comment: @bhorkarg yes you assumed correctly. I think I’m starting to understand this. Thanks. So even though a CORS policy is to be determined by the API server, if the requesting client somehow thinks it’s requesting info from the same origin, it will not concern itself with CORS? If so...what’s the use of CORS policy to begin with? Anyone can write a proxy in order to communicate with my API server and circumvent my policy (?).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106711/discussion-between-bhorkarg-and-zerohedge).